# Default implementation mapping for object without "_class" attribute in spring-data-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the next problem: at the start of the project I had only one implementation of some class:

```
class Wrapper {
    private Child child;
}

class Child { ... }
```

and when mongodb serializes this class it never set `_class` attribute for the `child` object.
Now I need to make the next classes structure:

```
class Wrapper {
    private Child child;
}

abstract class Child { ... }

class ChildA extends Child { ... }

class ChildB extends Child { ... }
```

Obviously, then I try to deserialize old documents, it throws an exception because it can't instantiate an abstract class.

The question is: is it any way to specify the default implementation for object deserialization? For example, I want to deserialize the `child` field into the `Child1` class if the `_class` attribute is not present like [this](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html#defaultImpl()) parameter in Jackson library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be the optimal solution, because I do suspect there are ways to control the mongo deserialization.  However, if you want to avoid digging into that well, you could use one of the [Mongo lifecycle events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events).  In particular, the **onAfterLoad** is dispatched after a document is read from the database, but before it has been converted into a java object.

So, using the event, you can examine the incoming json, and even change it before it gets converted... Here is an example for your situation:

```
@Component
public class WrapperRepositoryListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Wrapper> {

    @Override
    public void onAfterLoad(AfterLoadEvent<Wrapper> event) {
        Document doc = event.getDocument();
        Document child = (Document)doc.get("child");        
        if (!child.containsKey("_class")) {   
            child.put("_class", "ChildA");
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, (although I know this isn't the question you asked), depending on how much data you have out there, you could write a mongodb script that simply updates all of the existing records to have the _class field:

```
db.wrappers.update(
    { 
        "child" : { $exists : true},
        "child._class" : { $exists : false }
    }, 
    {
        $set:{
            "child._class" : "ChildA"
        }
    },    
    { 
        multi: true, 
        upsert: false    
    }
)
```